# F#: How can I define a computed property in a type?

Tags: c#, f#, computed-properties, c#-7.0, c#-to-f#

In C#, I can define a computed property as such:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string StartDateFormatted => StartDate.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd h:mm tt");
}
```

How can I do this in F#?

```
[<DataContract>]
[<CLIMutable>]
type MyViewModel = {
    [<DataMember>] StartDate            : DateTime
    [<DataMember>] StartDateFormatted   : string // How can I make this a computed property?
 }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very similar in F#:

```ml
open System

type MyViewModel() =
    member val StartDate = DateTime.Now
    member this.StartDateFormatted =
        this.StartDate.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd h:mm tt")

let model = MyViewModel()
printfn "%A" model.StartDateFormatted   // "2022.04.27 2:56 tt"
```

Note that I've used F#'s object syntax to define the type, rather than its record syntax. This is closer to what you're familiar with in C#.

If you want to use a record type, it would look something like this instead:

```ml
type MyViewModel =
    {
        mutable StartDate : DateTime
    }
    member this.StartDateFormatted =
        this.StartDate.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd h:mm tt")

let model = { StartDate = DateTime.Now }
printfn "%A" model.StartDateFormatted
```

Note that records are immutable by default, so aren't usually used for view-models (which, in an MVVM design, are updated to track changes made in the UI).

Comment: Can I implement the computed property with the record syntax? Was using the record syntax my problem?

Comment: @JimG. I've updated my answer to show you how to do it with a record type.

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much. Quick question though: Why does your code only work when the curly braces and the `member` keyword are indented? (I know - Rookie question!)

Comment: @JimG. F# has a "lightweight" syntax that's sensitive to indentation. You can get more info about it [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fsharp-syntax/).

Comment: Brian: Thanks so much! This is exactly why I couldn't map the documentation to my code. It's because I wasn't aware of the "lightweight" syntax. :)